# Error when merging pandas df. TypeError: ("object of type 'float' has no len()", 'occurred at index D')

Tags: python, pandas, merge

The code below effectively merges all values in a `pandas df` `row` before any 4 letter `string`. This only applies to rows directly underneath `X` in `Col A`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A' : ['X','Foo','No','','X','Big','No'],           
    'B' : ['','Bar','Merge','','','Cat','Merge'],
    'C' : ['','Fubu','XXXX','','','BgCt','YYYY'],                  
    })

maskX = df.iloc[:,0].apply(lambda x: x=='X')
maskX.index += 1
maskX = pd.concat([pd.Series([False]), maskX])
maskX = maskX.drop(len(maskX)-1)
mask = (df.iloc[:, 1:].applymap(len) == 4).cumsum(1) == 0

for i,v in maskX.items():
    mask.iloc[i,:] = mask.iloc[i,:].apply(lambda x: x and v)

df.A[maskX] = df.A + df.iloc[:, 1:][mask].fillna('').apply(lambda x: x.sum(), 1)
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:][~mask].fillna('')
```

This works fine unless there's values other than strings in the df. So if include floats or integers it returns an error to that Column. e.g

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A' : ['X','Foo','No','','X','Big','No'],           
    'B' : ['','Bar','Merge','','','Cat','Merge'],
    'C' : ['','Fubu','XXXX','','','BgCt','YYYY'],
    'D' : ['','',1.0,2.0,3.0,'',''],                   
    })

TypeError: ("object of type 'float' has no len()", 'occurred at index D')
```

I'm not quite sure why because the `merge` only occurs to the `row` beneath `X` in `Col A`. None of which contains `floats`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`applymap` applies the function `len` to each element of the dataframe. Since floating-point numbers do not have length, the function cannot be applied to them. If you still want to know their "length," convert them to strings:

```
df.iloc[:, 1:].astype(str).applymap(len)
```

However, be advised that the function `str` is not guaranteed to produce a particular string representation of a float. For example, `len(str(5.0000))` is 3, not 6, as you might expect.